# row of listView remains underLined

Tags: android, listview

i have a listView , and i'm not figuring out on how to underLine the row selected only for the time i click on it. With this code the row selected remains underlined after clicking on it and disappear when i select a new row.

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
```

list selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal" android:state_activated="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

is it possible to achieve this feature?

**UPDATE**

i want to achieve this feature.

[image]

and after

[image]

with this code the selected row doens't do what is described into screenshots,this one remains underlined.

thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your screen shoot .... its not clear what you have told ..

Comment: @Tanimreja ok wait a bit.

Comment: may be i got it .. problem is you list_selector file ...

Comment: @Tanimreja see updates i insert the list selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be helpful for you .
in your list_selector xml file please add this code

```
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

 </selector>
```

this code is work fine for me .. if face any problem then comment .. Thank you[image]