# changing the listview background color when mouse over it

Tags: android

i' developing a project in android which consist of a listview.my aim is that when we just touch any row of the listview or when we just place the mouse pointer over any list item its background color must be changed to grey color.this must be achieved also when we scroll it..can any one help me to slove it.

my code is

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    populateListView();


private void populateListView() {
String[] str={"apple,orange,grape,strawberry,guava,pineapple,etc"};
ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.textview,str);
ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listviewone);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

my activity_main.xml

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listviewone"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="#19bee6"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/listselect"
    android:scrollbars="none">
</ListView>
```

listselect.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/orange_color"/> 

<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_accelerated="true"     android:drawable="@drawable/red_color"/> 
<item android:state_hovered="true" android:drawable="@drawable/orange_color"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/red_color"/> 
<item android:state_active="true" android:drawable="@drawable/red_color"/> 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/textgradient"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can try with this:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black" android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_dark" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_dark" android:state_focused="true"/>

</selector>
```

Also you can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083200/row-of-listview-remains-underlined/26083685#26083685):

Comment: thanku for ur reply..i tried it but its not working.it is not changing the backround color when i touch the row of listview.

Comment: how to keep the row baground color as such until i press another row??